# Using nested loop to compare and process files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am writing a batch script that should loop through a folder in D:\PushIDs folder and check if the file exists in another drive E:

There are 1000+ files and I want to go through each one and compare all files with what's in E: drive.

If it exists and the file has appended: `ReadyForProcessing` to it, then, go back to D:\PushIDs and process that file.

The trick is the only thing I have to compare is a `date-time` portion of file name.

In `D:\PushIDs`  I have many files similar to this one, all that changes is `date-time`:

```
PushID.2015.03.25.03.12.00.xml
```

and in E: drive the file to compare would be:

```
TOMetadata.2015.03.25.03.12.00--ReadyForProcessing.xml
```

What I have so far:

```
for /f %%F in ('dir /b D:\PushIDs\') do (

    set pushID=%%~nF
    set dateTimePID=%pushID:~7%

    for /f %%M in ('dir /b E:\*.xml') do (

        set toFileName=%%~nM
        set dateTimeTO=%toFileName:~11,19%

        if "%dateTimePID%"=="%dateTimeTO%" (

            if "ReadyForProcessing"=="%toFileName:ReadyForProcessing%" (

                echo fileProcessing_logic
            )
        )

    )

)
```

But if I echo values, it keeps printing the same value 1000+ times

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please see endless articles on SO about `delayedexpansion`. Within a "block" (parenthesised series of statements) you need to invoke `delayedexpansion` and use `!var!` instead of `%var%` to access the environment variable values as they vary. (this explains the "same value" problem - since you are not using `setlocal` then the values you are displaying are those established in the previous trial run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the nested loop

```dos
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=.-" %%a in ('
    dir /b /a-d "e:\*ReadyForProcessing.xml"
') do if exist "d:\PushIDs\PushID.%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d.%%e.%%f.xml" (
    echo processing "d:\PushIDs\PushID.%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d.%%e.%%f.xml"
)
```

For each matching file in `e:` (name tokenized using the dot and dash as delimiters) if the corresponding file exists in `d:` process it.

Comment: I cannot make that work :( it echoes nothing and it processes nothing, because it exits immediately but I really like your suggestion and I will keep trying until I make it work. Thank you

Comment: @Angelina, my fault, sorry. I forget to include the dash in the list of delimiters to separate the `--ReadyForProcessing` from the seconds tokens when processing the list of files. Without it `%%f` contains wrong data. Now changed.